# Why the electronic configuration of samarium is ending with 4f⁶6s²

Tags: physical-chemistry, orbitals, electronic-configuration, stability, atomic-structure

What is coming in my mind is that 4f^7 6s^1 should be more stable as it allows two orbitals to be half filled rather than 4f^6 6s^2 in which only one orbital is completely filled....can someone please help me in this and tell that where I am thinking wrong....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the f-block elements is more stable to have a d1 orbital at the f7's next element (for instance, gadolinium, which has 6s2 4f7 5d1) than having the previous one with s1 configuration.

Comment: While this is perhaps true (the electronic configurations prove it), this doesn't actually explain anything. Could you add any more reasoning, or physical data, for this?